# Generate non-unique RSA key in C#

Tags: c#, cryptography

So I have a rather strange problem,

I'm working on a product which uses a cloud-keyvault for creation/storage of cryptographic keys and these keys are used in other applications to sign/validate data between one-another. The crypto-app generates a private-key for each app, and those other apps have that public-key stored in some configuration.

Now this works all fine and dandy, but to run this locally on our dev-machines we have to connect to a seperate dev-keyvault which also sits in the cloud. I'm trying to remove this dependency on the cloud in development runs.
My current attempt is to just generate RSA keys in the same way the cloud-vault does and store them in a file and this works pretty good, except that now every development-environment has a random private/public key-pair. This is annoying because we'd like to configure the development public keys for the other apps, so things just work during development without manual configuration by the devs.

To make this work I'd need this function to deterministically generate a key-pair (based on the app name or some other discriminator so based on this input you'd get the same key-pair every time. Is this even possible?

```
private static byte[] CreateNewPrivateKey(string keyName)
{
    using var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
    return rsa.ExportRSAPrivateKey();
}
```

Comment: generate a key-pair (per keyname), store it somewhere, then read that stored keypair instead of generating a new one?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Taht works on one machine, but on the next the keys would be a different pair, which is the problem Im trying to solve. Honestly I think Im just going to check the keys into the crypto-app repo or something. But deterministically generating keys would be a fun alternative

Comment: Deterministically generating RSA keys is hard because you need to go from a cryptographically secure input to a set of primes and that requires a determinsitic prime generation algorithm.  If you can use ECDSA keys instead, then it's a lot easier to map a 256-bit value onto a curve.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to look into other avenues to tackle my problem. If you create an answer saying 'nope' I'd accept it :)